# Why does part of the P-wave convert into a S-wave with an increase of incidence angle?

Tags: geophysics, seismology

With the increase of incidence angle, a portion of a P-wave converts into a S-wave, how does this behaviour occur?

Comment: Do you have a reference that states this?  (I am intrigued!)

Comment: @SabreTooth This phenomenon, known as **mode conversion**, is described by the [Zoeppritz equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoeppritz_equations), which are solutions to the [wave equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation). [Here's a nice demo video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ilDqQCezFFA) *How* this happens is, I think, rather a tricky question to answer without a lot of arm-waving.

Answer (score 2):

The way I imagine this phenomenon is illustrated in the picture below. I have to warn you that it lacks scientific accuracy and is **just a simple way to imagine** the effects we observe on a reflective boundary. However, it can be useful as a simple model you can easily imagine.
In the upper picture you can see an illustration of a [reflection event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_seismology#Reflection_and_transmission_at_non-normal_incidence) at a horizontal boundary.
The lower picture illustrates how the vector of particle motion in a down-going P-wave is 'decomposed' into two vectors. First component is a vector of particle motion in an up-going S-wave, the second corresponds to particle motion in an up-going P-wave.

Once again, **this is not how the rays exactly behave** in a reflection event. Here we do not take into account transmitted waves and lots of other factors. Nevertheless, sometimes you can use this 'approximation' because it satisfies two conditions:

- At normal incidence, there is no mode conversion (shear wave does not appear)
- As the incident angle increases, the amount of shear-wave energy increases too.

These effects are also observed in real life.
Exact description of a reflection event on a plane boundary, as [kwinkunks](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/70/kwinkunks) has  mentioned above, is given by Zoeppritz equations. They take into account all details and are widely-used. No doubt, they are much more difficult (but physically correct!) than a simple sketch I suggest.

[image: a very simple illustration of mode conversion].

Comment: Modelling shear-wave conversion does not show a monotonous increase of conversion energy as you can see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wBlkT.gif) which is taken from [Crewes](http://www.crewes.org/ResearchLinks/ConvertedWaves/page1.php).

Comment: Yes, thank you @WayoftheGeophysicist for your comment. As I have mentioned, Zoeppritz equations should be used for precise calculations. A useful and intuitive tool can be found here: [CREWES Zoeppritz Explorer](http://www.crewes.org/ResearchLinks/ExplorerPrograms/ZE/ZEcrewes.html). However, as you probably may have noticed, conversion energy always increases (by its absolute value) at small incidence angles and is equal to zero at normal incidence. And just to clarify: I do not propose an accurate model of reflection event, but rather a way to imagine this phenomenon.